# How can I list only last modified pdf files?

Tags: android, list, file, pdf, last-modified

I want to list only last modified pdf files in directory. Here is my adapter:

I have tried to add filter in the below code. But coming all files to my list not last modified pdf files. What am I doing wrong ?

```
public static ArrayList<File> mList;
    private static final String EXT = ".pdf";
    NavController navController;
    Context context;

    public PdfRecentListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.context = activity;
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        refreshRecent(Common.STORAGE_DIRECTORY);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
    }

    public void refreshRecent(File dir) {

        File fileList[] = dir.listFiles();

        if (fileList == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (File file : fileList) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                refreshRecent(file);
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(EXT)) {
                Arrays.sort(fileList, LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
                mList.add(file);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: I'm checking now. I have tried it before but checking again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

May be useful for you!

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator() {
                @SuppressWarnings("UseCompareMethod")
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    if (((File) o1).lastModified() > ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (((File) o1).lastModified() < ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                        return +1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: It's working fine but not working as I wanted. As I told u, I have tried it before. When I modified a pdf file, list didnt change.

Comment: May be possible your list not refreshed!

Comment: If so, then my list should be changing when I reopen the app or reopen the page. I don't think there's anything about refreshing my list